# Pattern matching input in haskell

Tags: function, haskell, pattern-matching

I have this piece of code

```
middleNumber:: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
middleNumber a b c 
         | a == b && a == c                  = a
         | a == b || a == c                  = a
         | b == c                            = b
         | b < a && a < c || c < a && a < b  = a 
         | a < b && b < c || c < b && b < a  = b
         | otherwise                         = c
```

I want to use pattern matching to catch all other input pattern, I tried to use

```
middleNumber _ = error "Wrong input"
```

and

```
middleNumber _ _ _ = error "Wrong input"
```

But they seem do not work. Appreciate any helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The patterns `a b c` already match any possible arguments that your function may receive, so any patterns you add in addition to that would just be unreachable code. There simply are no other input patterns for you to catch.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear which input is "wrong".

However, the otherwise-guard always evaluates to `True` and thus it will catch all orhter cases.

If you really have cases that are wrong input, then you should replace the `otherwise`-guard by the right condition. Finally, 
you can add as a last line, which will only be used if no guard evaluates to `True`.

```
middleNumber _ _ _ = error "Wrong input"
```

that is

```
middleNumber :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
middleNumber a b c 
         | a == b && a == c  = a
         | a == b || a == c  = a
         | b == c            = b
         | b < a && a < c || c < a && a < b  = a 
         | a < b && b < c || c < b && b < a  = b
         | ...conditions for c being the middle number... = c
middleNumber _ _ _ = error "Wrong input"
```

If no guard evaluates to `True` the last line catches all other cases.

Comment: Hmm, so what if the middle number is c ? Will this still return the value of c ?